# shp2pgsql dumping double fields with comma separator instead of dot

Tags: shp2pgsql

I guess the source shapefile is the culprit, but is there any way to change to fix it through shp2pgsql?

Obviously Postgres throw an error with: INSERT INTO "public"."a" ("area","perimeter", ...) VALUES ('5282,98830007762','313,033597376014', ...);

Comment: what is your locale? and did you tell postgis that?

Comment: Spanish which uses Comma as decimal separator. I can't recall PostGis installation asking me about that point

Comment: Anyway I don't think the shp2pgsql commnad uses that setting for converting

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem it was fixed by changing system locale to some locale with dot decimal separator, i.e.:

```
export LANG=en.UTF8
```

Comment: Just tried and it still outputs ",". Somehow locale seems to be tied to the source shp file. I'm using postgis 2.0.6